# Owin Authentication Single Sign-Out

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, single-sign-on, owin

I've got a custom Authentication middleware working for single sign-on. I'm wondering how I should go about implementing a single sign-out solution.

I need to call `Authentication.Signout()` to signout of my application, but I then need to redirect the user to the sign out endpoint of our custom STS. Where should I handle this? `Invoke`? `ApplyResponseGrant`? Not in the handler at all, but just a manual redirect?

**edit:**
This is an MVC app. I have everything working EXCEPT linking the local logout to logging out of the STS. Adding my existing code here would do nothing but obfuscate my question, IMO. If there is a specific piece of code that would help, let me know and I'll add it.

Ideally, I'd like some sort of event or flag that tells me the user is signing out, and then change the response into a 302 to the external logout. If I put this code in the `ApplyResponseGrant`, I have a feeling it will prevent the CookieAuthentication middleware from clearing the auth cookie. If I put this code in the Logout controller action (after a call to `Authentication.SignOut()`), then I leave it up to each application to handle the single sign off.

Comment: Is it an MVC or a WebApi application?

Comment: Have a look at this [blog post about `OWIN Authentication`.](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/29/Adding-minimal-OWIN-Identity-Authentication-to-an-Existing-ASPNET-MVC-Application). It covers    MVC, but most of the concepts you should be able to follow even if you build a WebApi application.

Comment: Also, when posting questions on SO, you should provide a minimum of code for us to understand the manner in which  you did that. Code is always more concise than words:)

Comment: I've added some more detail. I know what the code should do, I just don't know where to put it. I also fail to see why the type of web app should matter. The OWIN middleware runs outside of the application context.

Comment: You could make the logout as a method in the `AccountController`, log the user out and then do something like `    return RedirectToAction("LogOn");`
But unless you provide what code you have so far, this is all I can think of. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Matei, but I don't think you're understanding my question. I managed to get it figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Here's what I did.

In my `AccountController`, I added a `Logout` action that returns a `Redirect("/signout-custom")`.

In my OWIN handler, I watch for that URL in the `Invoke` method, call my remote sign out endpoint, the local sign out method, and stop OWIN processing.

```
public override async Task<bool> InvokeAsync() {
    //other code

    if (Request.Path == Options.LogoutCallbackPath) {
        Context.Authentication.SignOut(Options.AuthenticationType);
        Response.Redirect(WebUtilities.AddQueryString(Options.ClauthLogoutUri, "returnUrl", "http://localhost:62506/Home/About"));
        return true;
    }

    //other code

}
```

The redirect does not interrupt the OWIN flow, so the `CookieAuthentication` middleware still runs and clears the local auth cookie as it should.

Comment: How would you deal with the Timout?

Comment: That would be up to the client app. In this case, we're using standard cookie timeouts.

Comment: @spivonious where to put this function, in  startup? I have alike issue needs to follow your approach.

Comment: @user6395764 it's in my OWIN middleware component's Invoke method.