# ASP.NET MVC - WS Federation - Single Sign out

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, owin, adfs, ws-federation

I'm implementing SSO (Single Sign On and Single Sign Out) for my applications.
Let's say I have

1. Application "A" that is

   - Hosted on `https://app1.test.com`
   - Is registered in AD on-premise with `Wtrealm` same as `https://app1.test.com`
2. Application "B" that is

   - Hosted on `https://app2.test.com`
   - Is registered in AD on-premise with `Wtrealm` same as `https://app2.test.com`

I've used this blog as reference to implement Single Sign On in both the application.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sakamati/2015/07/06/creating-owin-based-ws-federation-application/

The problem I'm facing with is for Single Sign Out.
When I do sign out in one application, the session in other application still remains active.

**What am I missing so that the Single Sign Out will work for both the application?**

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Is registered in AD on-premise" do you mean "Is registered in ADFS on-premise"?

Are you following the steps as per [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1439.ad-fs-how-to-invoke-a-ws-federation-sign-out.aspx) using "wa=wsignout1.0"?

Comment: Yes, I meant the applications are registed in ADFS on-premise.
Also, I'm following that the link. The problem is, by using that sign-out link, I'm able to logout one application but the other application doesn't (since it's unaware that the sign-out as happened at Identify Server)

Comment: Check that your LogoutUri is set for all of your clients. ADFS does its best, but you need to implement logic to handle the request and take action to sign-out the user.

Also, make sure that the client application has dropped all authenticated artifacts after a sign-out request was received at the registered LogoutUri. If they still have a valid refresh token, ADFS will still issue the access token.

It might also be useful to reference this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32460101/7447383

Comment: @R.McManaman - Does ADFS sends a logout request to replying party registered in ADFS?
I'm still confused as to how other application would know that a logout was requested by another application?

Comment: Have a look at SLO - https://www.portalguard.com/blog/2016/06/20/saml-single-logout-need-to-know/

Answer (score 0):

1 First way in ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
.AddWsFederation(options =>
            {
                options.MetadataAddress = stsConfig.MetadataAddress;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider += OnRedirect;
                options.Events.OnRemoteSignOut = async context =>
                {
                    await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    return;
                };
            });
```

2 Second way.

ADFS do GET to /signin-wsfed with params to app1 when you signout in app2.
I can't found documentation about it, but see it in debug and logs.
For Asp.net Core 3.1

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddScoped<WsFederationAuthCleanupMiddleware>();
   ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   ...
   app.UseMiddleware<WsFederationAuthCleanupMiddleware>();
   ...
   app.UseAuthentication();
   ...
}

public class WsFederationAuthCleanupMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<WsFederationAuthCleanupMiddleware> _logger;

    public WsFederationAuthCleanupMiddleware(ILogger<WsFederationAuthCleanupMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        var request = context.Request;

        // could look for a specific path as well...
        if (request.Query.TryGetValue("wa", out var wa) && wa == "wsignoutcleanup1.0")
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("WsFederationAuthCleanupMiddleware with {@Query}", request.Query);
            // Your signin scheme probably cookies
            request.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }            

        return next(context);
    }
}
```